# Monotonic sequence defined by a function

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, where $f$ is bijective and continuous , if $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, then I have to prove that $\forall x \in (0,1)$ we have that the orbit of $x$ is a monotonic sequence, i.e. $f^{n} (x) \leq f^{n+1} (x)$ or $f^{n} (x) \geq f^{n+1} (x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know if $f$ is bijective then $f$ is increasing or decreasing. Can anybody give me an idea?

Comment: Note that your comment "i.e. $f^n(x)\leq f^{n+1}(x)$ or $f^n(x)\geq f^{n+1}(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$." isn't what you meant.  This is trivial.  Instead, it should be "i.e. $f^n(x)\leq f^{n+1}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $f^n(x)\geq f^{n+1}(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$."

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, then $f$ is increasing.  That is, $f$ is order-preserving, and hence $f^n$ is order-preserving (prove this by induction on $n$ if you want).  I.e. $$0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1 \implies f^n(a) \leq f^n(b)$$

Now, for any $x \in (0,1)$, we have either $x \leq f(x)$ or $x \geq f(x)$.  Suppose $x \leq f(x)$.  Then by using the above fact, we conclude $f^n(x) \leq f^n(f(x)) = f^{n+1}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.